# Why is there no optimization for checking for empty string via "" comparison?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14

This google-benchmark code checked on [Quick Bench](http://quick-bench.com/_hh9c4HmeEAYj_z_oZOIHgQ_zq4), shows that `string::empty()` runs a lot faster than comparing with an empty-string literal. However, creating a name string of `""` actually makes the compiler optimize away the check:

```cpp
bool compareWithNamedConst(const std::string& target) {
    const std::string emptyString = "";
    return emptyString == target;
}

bool compareWithLiteral(const std::string& target) {
    return "" == target;
}

bool compareWithRvalue(const std::string& target) {
    return std::string{""} == target;
}

bool checkForEmpty(const std::string& target) {
    return target.empty();
}
```

The performance for each of the calls is shown here:

[image]

As you can see, comparing with `""` is very slow compared to all the other options. I wonder why it is the case? It must be somehow related to SSO not being applied on `const char*`, as testing this:

```cpp
bool compareWithLiteral(const std::string& target) {
    return "test with a longer string not optimized" == target;
}

bool compareWithRvalue(const std::string& target) {
    return std::string{"test with a longer string not optimized"} == target;
}
```

Results comparing with a literal actually being faster:

[image]

I find that checking for string emptiness, the easiest syntax to read is `"" == myVariable` as it clearly indicates that `myVariable` is a `std::string` with no unneccesary clutter. Why can't we have it optimized as we have all the other cases?

Comment: with which optimization are you running those examples?

Comment: `-O3` on gcc and clang

Comment: compareWithLiteral is the only case when you are comparing objects of different types. I'm guessing that's the root cause here. I'm not so sure the compiler is allowed to "optimize away" an implicit conversion.

Comment: fwiw, using `lenght() == 0` instead of `empty()` is also a good hint that it is a string and does not require to use a string literal, though which is more readable is of course opinions

Comment: can't say why, but on compiler explorer you can see that in the second case with -O3 its generating A LOT more code to handle the rvalue string, where in the case of the const char * not

Comment: You're not "naming the string literal" though, you're constructing a std::string object from it and using a completely different overload of the equality operator. Naming a string literal without conversion or decay is tricky, but possible.

Comment: @Useless I call it naming the literal, because I have seen codebases, where people actually used `EMPTY_STRING = whatever_string_representation("")`. I was like wth is the reason here? And now I see that the performance can be improved just by doing that.

Comment: It seems that `"" == std::string()` calls `strcmp`, while `std::string() == std::string()` calls `memcmp`. My guess is that knowing sizes of strings in advance allows `std::string::operator==(std::string)` to compare size straight away. [this compare](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L155) vs [this compare](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L347)

Comment: Yes, but the literal and the thing you named are different objects. You didn't name the literal, but create a new named object with a mutable copy of the literal. The distinction is significant here, because it means you're using a different equality operator than you suggest.

Comment: @Useless all right, I reword the question :)

Comment: @KamilCuk should that not be possible for the `""` `const char*` literal as well? I find it very strange that this is not optimizable.

Comment: @ÁdámHunyadi For a `char const*` parameter there’s not much the *library* can do, the *compiler* would have to perform optimisation on some fairly complex code. The *library* could presumably fix that by overloading `operator==` for type `char(&)[1]`.

Comment: Compiler might detect `"" == s`, but from language point of view, we only have `operator ==(const char*, const std::string&)`. There is a dedicated method to check for empty, which is the way to go IMO.

Answer (score 1):

For emptyness check, if you really like the literal syntax, you may help your compiler by `using namespace std::string_literals;`, and replacing `""` with `""s`. In that case `compareWithLiteral`, `compareWithRvalue` and `checkForEmpty` would be essentially the same, since the `operator==` between `const std::string&` usually checks the sizes before the content, and the size of `""s` is trivial.

```
bool compareWithLiteral(const std::string& target) {
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    return ""s == target;
}
```

For strings not falling into the SSO, you should try with `std::string_view` and its `operator""sv`, even if unfortunately is available only since C++17. Boost has `boost::string_view`. No user string literal is provided for compile time creation (essential because the test string length would be hardcoded in the binary), but you can easily define one:

```
#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>

constexpr auto operator""_sv(const char* str, std::size_t len) noexcept {
    return boost::basic_string_view<char>{str, len};
}

bool compareWithLiteral(const std::string& target) {
    return "test with a longer string not optimized"_sv == target;
}
```

This version runs much faster than your `compareWithLiteral` version, at least when `target` size is different.

Comment: While true (and IMHO good advice), this doesn’t answer OP’s question at all, which wasn’t *how* do perform the check efficiently, but rather *why* the comparison with a C-style string isn’t optimised.

Comment: @KonradRudolph agreed, my question is about what is preventing the compiler seeing a short c style string of size zero and just completely skip looping through its content until `\0`, because it is empty.

Comment: I see, but why should you rely the performances of the code on the compiler optimization, when the language provides the tools for a predictive behavior almost for free?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main difference is that comparison that involves `std::string` objects first only *checks their sizes*. If they are not equal, the comparison *immediately returns*. (That's also might explain why `memcmp` may be then used if both strings are of equal lengths, as pointed out by @KamilCuk.)

On the contrary, with literals, these are treated as C-strings/char-arrays where no information about their lengths are provided. Therefore, `strcmp` function is used inside which has *larger overhead*, even in case that one of the string is empty (at least, the overhead of a function call since `strcmp` seems to be not inlined in your assembly).

As for the last question, `compareWithRvalue`, there the string is too large for SSO, therefore, *dynamic memory allocation* (and deallocation) is performed (and likely not optimized away here), which represents a relatively large overhead here.

Comment: Let's say I have a simple implementation for comparing against a `const char*` by looping until I see `\0` and checking characters. The compiler *can* know it in compile time that the first thing it will read will be a `\0`. Why does it still not optimize the check away?

Comment: @ÁdámHunyadi First, you can try this implementation in quick-bench. Second, that's a question for compiler writers. Optimization abilities are very powerful in modern compilers, but are not all-mighty.

Comment: @ÁdámHunyadi I tried your proposed custom implementation and [it was just slightly slower than the other options](http://quick-bench.com/HQvMf9s2qwBcZUXIN_hfTkbaHF4). Note that `while (*p1 && ...)`. If it was switched to `while (*p2 && ...`, then it run much much slower. The compiler is obviously aware at compile time of `*p1` being zero.